# Optimistic locking in PowerBI when embedding reports in edit mode

Tags: save, report, edit, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

We are embedding PowerBI reports for out-of-organization users using the PowerBI JavaScript API. When using **edit mode**, it seems that save conflicts are not handled in any way. The situation is quite rare for us, but nonetheless it should be handled properly. For example:

- User A opens a report in edit mode
- User B opens the same report, makes an edit, and saves
- User A then saves his/her changes after user B, effectively overwriting user B's changes

I would have assumed, that there would be at least an informative message displayed in this kind of situation (e.g. with optimistic locking), but it doesn't seem to be the case.

I am wondering if there is something in the APIs themselves that we are missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not special locking between 2 customers or clients editing and saving at the same time. you can notice that the save operation is saving the differences done in edit, such that you would get the aggregation of the 2 edits.

Power BI Embedded in these cases acts no different than the PowerBI.com website.

However, in cases where the edits might conflict and cannot be resolved in Power BI automatically, you might get a 400 (Bad Request) response when doing the save operation, with the proper IError object transferred to the application via the JS SDK.